# Docusign:Callbacks from connect are consolidated instead of separate callbacks

Tags: docusignapi

We are using Electronic Seal functionality. And we have configured Docusign Connect for callbacks on recipients and envelope events

**Envelope Events** : 
Envelope Signed/Completed, Envelope Declined, Envelope Voided

**Recipient Events** :
Recipient Signed/Completed, Recipient Declined

There are two recipients in this order

1. Signer 2. Electronic Seal

When signer signs the agreement. The agreement goes for Electronic seal automatically in Docusign.

Our application expects 2 callbacks.

**First Callback** for signer signed - **InProcess**

**Second Callback** for **Completed**.

But Docusign Connect is giving us just **one consolidated callback of Completed**. The InProcess callback never comes to our endpoint.

This is also very account specific.
For our demo account the callbacks are separate, but for our customer's demo account the callbacks are consolidated.

My Assumption is the higher notification is sent and the lower notification is skipped.

1. Is **Envelope Signed/Completed Event** higher than **Recipient Signed/Completed Event**.
2. If I only subscribe to **Recipient Signed/Completed** events and **not Envelope Event** will I get both callbacks since these are equal ?
3. Is there any other setting in Connect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the default Connect webhook queuing algorithm is "aggregate queuing" -- if a notification message is superseded by a subsequent notification event that you subscribed to, and the first message has not been sent out yet, then only the second message will be sent.

In addition, the message content is generated when the message is sent, not when the event occurs.

Sounds like you want the newer queuing method, SIM (Send Intermediate Messages). Turn this on via the **Updates** section of the administration tool. All webhook notifications for envelopes sent from the account will be affected.